# Join two values to get the description in other table-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a scenario where I need to join two values and find the material desc.

```
Product table :
-------------
PRODUCT    SUGGESTIONS
item1       item2
item1       item3
item1       item3&item4
item1       item2&item3

Product Master table:
--------------------

PRODUCT      DESC
item1        EBIKE
item2        BIKE TOOLS
item3        BIKE PAINT
item4        Regular Bike
```

The output should

```
PRODUCT    SUGGESTIONS    PRODUCT DESC
item1       item2          BIKE TOOLS
item1       item3          BIKE PAINT
item1       item3&item4    BIKE PAINT& Regular Bike
item1       item2&item3    BIKE TOOLS&BIKE PAINT
```

I am not sure how to join these two tables. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using substring matches (i.e. using `INSTR()` or `LIKE`) then there is the issue of making partial matches (i.e. `item1` is a sub-string of `item11`) and you need to handle this case.

Assuming the delimiter you are using is never going to be part of the product id then you can use:

```
SELECT PT.PRODUCT,
       PT.SUGGESTIONS,
       LISTAGG(PM.DESC, '&') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PM.DESC)
         AS PRODUCT_DESC 
FROM   PRODUCT PT
       INNER JOIN
       PRODUCTMASTER PM 
       ON ( '&'||PT.SUGGESTIONS||'&' LIKE '%&'||PM.PRODUCT || '&%' )
GROUP BY PT.PRODUCT, PT.SUGGESTIONS
```

However a better solution would be to properly separate the product and suggestions into individual tables:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id      NUMBER(8,0)  CONSTRAINT product__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  product VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT product__product__u UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE suggestions (
  id          NUMBER(8,0) CONSTRAINT product_suggestions__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id  NUMBER(8,0) CONSTRAINT product_suggestions__pid__fk
                                     REFERENCES products ( id )
                          CONSTRAINT product_suggestions__pid__nn NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE product_suggestions (
  suggestion_id NUMBER(8,0) CONSTRAINT product_suggestions__sid__fk
                                       REFERENCES suggestions ( id ),
  product_id    NUMBER(8,0) CONSTRAINT product_suggestions__sid__fk
                                       REFERENCES product ( id ),
  CONSTRAINT product_suggestions__pk PRIMARY KEY ( suggestion_id, product_id )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not a good table design. You're using form that is not ok for normalization rules.

This may work for this case.

```
SELECT PT.PRODUCT, PT.SUGGESTIONS, LISTAGG(PM.DESC, '&') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PM.DESC) AS PRODUCT_DESC 
FROM PRODUCT PT, PRODUCTMASTER PM 
WHERE INSTR(PT.SUGGESTIONS,PM.PRODUCT) != 0
GROUP BY PT.PRODUCT, PT.SUGGESTIONS
```

Comment: @MKN It will not work if you have `item1` and `item13`.

Comment: @MT0:Could you please let me know the reason and what to do in that case.

Comment: @MKN if you have `item13&item21` then `INSTR()` will match `item1`, `item2`, `item13` and `item21` as sub-strings of that.

Comment: My answer just work for your sample but as I understand you have much more data.. In your case @MT0's answer will work for your cases.. As I mention before this table design will get you more trouble in the future..